# Bash Script Array compare issue

Tags: bash

I have the following code in my script:

```
RESULT=$(cora_cmd --input={connect hrdwtst01.campbellsci.com';' file-control $STATION_NAME stop-program';' bye';'})
declare y
IFS=$'\n' y=($RESULT)
echo ${y[2]}
if [ ${y[2]} == '-file-control,loggernet datalogger locked' ]; then
    echo -e "\t\E[31;1m.. ERROR - Not able to stop the datalogger's program. ..\E[37;0m"
fi
echo "$RESULT"
```

The compare is not working and it never goes into the if statement.  Any ideas?

Results of the set -x:

```
'++ cora_cmd '--input={connect' 'hrdwtst01.campbellsci.com;' file-control TS_CR850_PB_801 'stop-program;' 'bye;}'
+ RESULT='CoraScript 1, 13, 06 Beta
+connect,"coralib3.dll version 1, 7, 18 Beta"
'file-control,loggernet datalogger locked
+ declare y
+ IFS='
'
+ y=($RESULT)
' echo '-file-control,loggernet datalogger locked
-file-control,loggernet datalogger locked
' '!=' '-file-control,loggernet datalogger locked' ']'
+ echo -e '\t\E[31;1m.. ERROR - Not able to stop the datalogger'\''s program.   ..\E[37;0m'
    .. ERROR - Not able to stop the datalogger's program. ..'
```

Comment: Do you really have backticks around the whole thing in your script, or was that your incorrect way to do SO markup?

Comment: No.  That was just stackoverflow's addition.

Comment: Try replacing your first echo line with something like `echo "(${y[2]})" | cat -vet` to check for additional characters you don't expect to be there. In particular, due to how you're using `IFS`, you may have other whitespace attached to your array entries...

Comment: (-file-control,loggernet datalogger locked^M)$

Comment: So there's a stray `^M` on there indicating that your `cora_cmd` output includes DOS-style `\r\n` line endings, and you're only stripping off the `\n`, leaving the carriage return character. That's why you're not getting a match...

Answer (score 0):

Always quote your variables unless you know you want word splitting and globbing to be done on the expansion.

```
if [ "${y[2]}" = '-file-control,loggernet datalogger locked' ]; then
```

You can also use the built-in `[[` syntax, which doesn't do word splitting of variables.

```
if [[ ${y[2]} = '-file-control,loggernet datalogger locked' ]]; then
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried both of those and neither worked.

Comment: maybe the variable has spaces at the beginning or end? What does `echo "|${y[2]}|"` show?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script so it will show all the commands with variables expanded as it runs.

Comment: Thanks Barmer.  The set-x is very handy!

Comment: Post it in a code block in the question so the formatting will be kept.

Answer (score 0):

> So there's a stray `^M` on there indicating that your `cora_cmd` output
>   includes DOS-style `\r\n` line endings, and you're only stripping off
>   the `\n`, leaving the carriage return character. That's why you're not
>   getting a match... –  twalberg

twalberg correctly diagnosed the problem. The simple solution is of course to include `\r` in IFS:

```
IFS=$'\r\n' y=($RESULT)
```

Including the `\r` in the test `== $'-file-control,loggernet datalogger locked\r'` is also possible.